# CPU limitations on RAM upgrade

Tags: memory, cpu

My system uses a Celeron 1.4GHz with 2GB RAM.

I would like to upgrade my RAM for photo-imaging software requirements to either 4GB or 8GB.

Will the program workload still be highly dependent on the limitations of the CPU, regardless of whether I get an 8gb over a 4gb upgrade?

Comment: The limitations of read/write to disk depend on the motherboard and disk controller. The CPU will convert images at the same speed that it does now. This seems like a very old computer, newer computers will be enormously faster.

Comment: @harrymc The Celeron CPU is still being made if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @harrymc My mistake given the spec of the cpu (1.4GHz) the OP posted, you are right.  Its an old CPU.

Comment: Will I gain noticeably better performance with an 8gb upgrade over a 4gb?